# Where to put SnapshotListener (Firestore) in MVVM

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, mvvm, repository-pattern

So I've searched for a while now but didn't got a specific answer for my question.

I'm implementing MVVM right now in my android studio project and I really don't know "the best practice" of where to put my snapshot-listeners throughout the app. If I place them in my Repository classes I need to handle the upcoming document changes in my ViewModel after the snapshot gives a return of the changes. Or I can place it directly in my ViewModel and modify my LiveData from there.

So what is "the best practice" of this ?

```
//I've already implemented it in my Repository the function looks like this :

    fun setSnapshotListener(): HashMap<String, MutableList<DepotModel>>? {
        currentUser?.let { user ->
            if (depotListenerRegistration == null) {
                depotListenerRegistration =
                    firebaseFirestore.collection("Example").document("example2").collection("Example3")
                        .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error ->
                            if (querySnapshot != null && querySnapshot.documents.isNotEmpty()) {
                                val hm = hashMapOf<DocumentChange.Type, MutableList<DepotModel3>>().apply { 
                                    this[DocumentChange.Type.ADDED] = mutableListOf()
                                    this[DocumentChange.Type.MODIFIED] = mutableListOf()
                                    this[DocumentChange.Type.REMOVED] = mutableListOf()
                                }
                                querySnapshot.documentChanges.forEachIndexed { _, depotDoc ->
                                    when (depotDoc.type) {
                                        DocumentChange.Type.ADDED
hm[DocumentChange.Type.ADDED]?.add(addedDepot)
                                        }

                                        DocumentChange.Type.MODIFIED -> {
hm[DocumentChange.Type.MODIFIED]?.add(addedDepot)

                                            }

                                        }

                                        DocumentChange.Type.REMOVED -> {
hm[DocumentChange.Type.REMOVED]?.add(addedDepot)

                                            }

                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                return hm
                            
                            }
                            else if (error != null) {
                                return null
                            }
                        }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, the `SnapshotListener` should be used inside the repository class. Since you're using Kotlin, I recommend you use Flow. So I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-make-a-clean-architecture-android-app-using-mvvm-firestore-and-jetpack-compose-abdb5e02a2d8) might help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreCleanArchitectureApp).

Answer (score 2):

Sharing this as a community wiki for the benefit of others

As mentioned by @Alex Mamo

> No, the SnapshotListener should be used inside the repository class. Since you're using Kotlin, I recommend you use Flow. So I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-make-a-clean-architecture-android-app-using-mvvm-firestore-and-jetpack-compose-abdb5e02a2d8) might help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreCleanArchitectureApp).